# Windows form missing border

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image

I'm in a bit of a bind.
I'm currently working on a windows form application and just doing the finishing touches.

I've run into a small graphical problem.

I have a form, which consists of two panels and a picturebox. All of these have images attached, forming the entire form. I'll link to these three pictures seperately aswell as the final picture. Just in case that has something to do with it.

[image]

Looking at the picture, there seems to be a border around the form, which is what is expected.
But looking at the bottom and the left side of the form, the border isn't there.

I've checked that the sizes of the pictures add up with the size of the farm, no dice there.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

I've attached the links to the three seperate parts of the picture underneath.

[Top part of the picture](http://imageshack.us/a/img542/8246/k3g9.png)

[Center part of the picture](http://imageshack.us/a/img841/2139/bfxl.jpg)

[Bottom part of the picture](http://imageshack.us/a/img41/5971/jthf.jpg)

EDIT:

[More code for drawing](http://pastebin.com/QrY31ue8)

[Even more code for drawing](http://pastebin.com/Xnx5FWBS)

Comment: This may be due to Windows Theme setting or form's border style property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . Also, I suggest you try capturing the picture on a blank bacground so people could see better.

Comment: @EmmadKareem - Updated the picture with a blank background ;-)
I'll be checking the stuff you mentioned and update!

Comment: Show your drawing code.  It looks like it's off by a pixel or two on the width and height.

Comment: @LarsTech - Edited with the drawing code :-)

Comment: That doesn't look like drawing code.

Comment: @LarsTech - Updated again - Total brainfart -_-

Comment: @NicholasMagnussen Do you have any margin or padding applied to your panels or picture boxes?

Comment: @philreed - 3; 3; 3; 3 margin, 0; 0; 0; 0 padding, to both panels and the picturebox

Comment: @LarsTech seems to be thinking along the same lines as me with his answer but I was going to suggest removing the margin and seeing what difference it made.

Comment: @philreed - Thank you for your help either way :-)

Comment: Perhaps this is a computer and OS specific problem? See this question and comments there for rationale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183236/winform-form-border-issue-in-windows-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a pixel to your rounded rectangle:

```
path.AddArc(bounds.Left, bounds.Top, radius, radius, 180, 90)
path.AddArc(bounds.Right - radius + 1, bounds.Top, radius, radius, 270, 90)
path.AddArc(bounds.Right - radius + 1, bounds.Bottom - radius + 1, radius, radius, 0, 90)
path.AddArc(bounds.Left, bounds.Bottom - radius + 1, radius, radius, 90, 90)
```

That being said, your solution isn't very reliable since it seems to rely on the form being 386 pixels in width, which might not always be the case when a computer uses different font sizes or DPI settings.

WinForms does not have great support for rounded corners with smooth gradients.

Comment: Your answer fixed it for me. I'll have to deal with how it looks on screen with different font sizes or DPI settings when it's a problem!

Thank you very much for your assistance