# Winform form border issue in windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to WinForms, so need your expert advice on this issue that I am facing when I deploy my Winform Application in Window 10 Pro environment. I see that the dialog form which has FormBorderStyle set to SizableToolWindow(or FixedToolWindow for that matter) doesnt paint the Borders on all side on the window except on top.

**Border Issue when FormBorderStyle is set to SizableToolWindow**
[image: Border Issue when FormBorderStyle is set to SizableToolWindow]

**Border is seen when FormBorderStyle is set to FixedSingle**
[image: Border is seen when FormBorderStyle is set to FixedSingle]

Sample Complete Code is given below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Is there a solution which can override this behavior maybe just for windows 10?

EDIT: I observed that when I set the ControlBox Property of the Form to false the client site is only shown and has the complete border but then the Caption bar is not visible.

Comment: If you put mouse pointer on the edges, it will show the resize cursor when FormBorderStyle is set to SizableToolWindow

Comment: Isn't that how a tool window should look?

Comment: Hi EpicKip, the tool Box should not have the minimize and maximize button on the top, but the active window border should come on all three side (Left, Right and Bottom)

Comment: I think that's a Win10 thing, not much you can do about it.

Comment: I had an issue like this. I found that resizing the window with mouse would make it disappear and reappear, depending on the size. To fix I changed the height of my form (Form.ClientSize). Probably on other computers it will still not show sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would say the behavior and the rendering depends on the operating system and I think there is no real answer to your question.

However, you can create custom form/window and you can use it as a tool window or however you want.

First, you would need to set the FormBorderStyle to None

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Then you can override the OnPaint method and draw your border there like the code below

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle borderRectangle = new Rectangle(1, 1, ClientRectangle.Width - 2, ClientRectangle.Height - 2);

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, borderRectangle);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
```

The outcome would be something like in the image below:
[image]

Please note that you will have to take care of other things like giving the ability to this form to be moved around, make sure you add custom close button etc.

Once you have this done, you can use this form as a base class and inherit your future form classes from that one.

The complete code of that custom form would be:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomForm
{
    public partial class CustomBorderForm : Form
    {
        public CustomBorderForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle borderRectangle = new Rectangle(1, 1, ClientRectangle.Width - 2, ClientRectangle.Height - 2);

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, borderRectangle);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Seems like the only logical approach. Thanks for the answer